# Need to stretch TextView spans to fill whole view

Tags: android, xamarin.android, textview, spannablestring

Is there any solution to stretch my text spans to parent bounds and take similar amount of space for each one? Desired result:

[image: desired]

I have now:

[image]

P.S. I am trying to use spans to draw week (may try month later) because page drawing will be to slow with 365+ TextViews for each day.

Comment: use `\t` between each value.

Comment: it is not solution for the problem..

Comment: Did you try my solution? Any update?

Comment: I did not try to use native CalendarView because I was not sure I can customize it to fit my purposes.
I tried to use GridViews previously and it was rather slow. 
At the end of the day I have implemented my feature using SpannableStringBuilder and I will post solution on my weekend.
Nevertheless thank you for your advices.

Answer (score 0):

Since you didn't post any of your code, I don't know how you achieve your layout.

But if you want to customize your own calendar view instead of the provided [CalendarView](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/CalendarView.html) component of native Android, you may use `GridView`, which displays items in a two-dimensional, scrollable grid. The grid items are automatically inserted to the layout using a `ListAdapter`.

This will be absolutely solve the alignment issue of `TextView`, you may take a look at the sample of using `GridView` here: [Grid View](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/user_interface/grid_view/).

Also you may refer to this blog to use `GridView` to create custom calendar: [Android Customization: How to Build a UI Component That Does What You Want](https://www.toptal.com/android/android-customization-how-to-build-a-ui-component-that-does-what-you-want), this is java for native Android, but for Xamarin, they're quite similar.

Answer (score 0):

As you have not mentioned any code,i would like to give you a gist of what i did to make calendar to cover whole width(with equal spacing date blocks):

```
 <StackLayout>
<Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                    <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                                    <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                                    <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                                    <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                                    <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                                    <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                                    <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <StackLayout Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0">
                                    <Label Text="1"/>
                                </StackLayout>
and so on...
</StackLayout>
```